# How to find out how many other instances are running, from within code, on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Is there some way to have my Node app find out how many instances are running, and perhaps get some kind of ID of the instance it's running on? I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: please include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the app engine api, here is the documentation for the rest API https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.services.versions.instances/list